# Fill Missing Dates for Running Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

| UserID | Date | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05-01 | 3 |
| A | 2021-05-03 | 1 |
| A | 2021-05-03 | 2 |
| A | 2021-05-05 | 5 |
| B | 2021-05-02 | 4 |
| B | 2021-05-03 | 10 |

What I need is something that looks like this.

| UserID | Date | DailySale | RunningSale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05-01 | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2021-05-02 | NULL | 3 |
| A | 2021-05-03 | 3 | 6 |
| A | 2021-05-04 | NULL | 6 |
| A | 2021-05-05 | 5 | 11 |
| B | 2021-05-01 | NULL | 0 |
| B | 2021-05-02 | 4 | 4 |
| B | 2021-05-03 | 10 | 14 |
| B | 2021-05-04 | NULL | 14 |
| B | 2021-05-05 | NULL | 14 |

I need to join on itself with all the dates in a certain time period so I can create a running sum sales total by date.
I figured out how to do it all separately, I know how to do a running sum using (over partition by) and I know I can join a calendar table to my sales table to get the time period. But I want to try the self join method by distinct(datetime), and I'm not certain how to go about that. I've tried this, but it doesn't work for me. I have over 1 million rows, so it takes over 2 minutes to finished processing and the running-sum column looks exactly like the daily-sum column.

What's the best way to go about this?

Edit: Corrected Table Sums

Comment: Please check you expected output as the numbers there don't completely agree with your sample data above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a calendar table here containing all dates.  Consider the following approach:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2021-05-01' AS Date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-05-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-05-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-05-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-05-05'
)

SELECT
    u.UserID,
    d.Date,
    SUM(t.Sale) AS DailySale,
    SUM(COALESCE(SUM(t.Sale), 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY u.UserID ORDER BY d.Date) AS RunningSale
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM yourTable) u
CROSS JOIN dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.UserID = u.UserID AND t.Date = d.Date
GROUP BY
    u.UserID,
    d.Date
ORDER BY
    u.UserID,
    d.Date
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: We prefer data as tabular text over images :)

Comment: @DaleK I generally agree with you, but in this case I also dropped a demo link (which admittedly could break at any point in the future).

Comment: @Question, I followed your logic and I get for the t.date part, I get Column 't.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I don't

Comment: ... that's why I don't select `t.date`, I select `d.date`.  Please use my demo as your starting point, do not just copy and paste here and there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I typed that wrong. My issues were more to do with me over thinking things and wanted to show both dates in a redundant way. Also, it took me a while to get the hang of using cte with my original tables. I got it all sorted though! Thank you very much for your help.